# change text dynamically svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this structure I want to change the text dynamically  in balise 
I searched on the net but I didn't find the right solution

```html
<g node-id="itemdat-1" style="opacity: 1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-170,115)" class="node" level="1"><rect x="0" y="0" height="55" width="150" fill="#039BE5" stroke-width="1" stroke="#aeaeae" rx="5" ry="5"></rect><text width="230" class="field_0" style="font-size: 18px;" fill="#ffffff" x="75" y="35" text-anchor="middle">Module 1</text><g data-edit-id-filed="itemdat-1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,130,5)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap svg in a div with contenteditable set to make all the text inside editable. One caveat is that if you delete all the text, you'll delete the text node and you can't really recover from that.

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
<svg viewBox="-200 80 200 100">
<g node-id="itemdat-1" style="opacity: 1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-170,115)" class="node" level="1"><rect x="0" y="0" height="55" width="150" fill="#039BE5" stroke-width="1" stroke="#aeaeae" rx="5" ry="5"></rect><text class="field_0" style="font-size: 18px;" fill="#ffffff" x="75" y="35" text-anchor="middle">Module 1</text>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but you changed the text manually, I want dynamically it's user who changes the text

Comment: contenteditable kind of works. Short of writing a complete editor that's the best you'll get.

Comment: yes but in my example it not works because my plugin used  totally svg

Comment: You'll have to write an editor then. That's far too big a task to answer from scratch. Have at it and write a question on any specific issue when you get stuck.